# Java webstart cannot access jar file

Tags: java, jar, classloader, java-7, java-web-start

Has anyone tried the method to retrieve files from jars using Java webstart and Java 7.51? The major changes made where signing the jars:

```
URL url= Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(path);
```

or

```
URL url= MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path);;
```

This is the method I had which worked perfect on previous Java versions. Now with Java 7.51 this returns null. Also does anyone know if this was a bug and has been fixed on latest updates of Java?

`getResourceAsStream` does not work either.

Comment: I don't know, but my understanding is that Java7U51 is now unsupported due to only the last 2 revs staying in support.  Currently those are U55 and U60.

Comment: What about `getClass().getResource(path)`?  Does that fail as well?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes that fails as well

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch have you by any chance tried this method with these new versions of java?